# NGINX proxy request timeouts after NGINX runs for several days

Tags: nginx, timeout, reverse-proxy, nginx-reverse-proxy, proxypass

I'm running a webapp on an AWS EKS cluster with an NGINX reverse proxy on a separate EC2 instance. After a few days of NGINX running it happens, that some of the requests (maybe 15-20 % of them) time out. I added logging to all layers of the application to see where the requests actually gets lost. My tech stack is

- NGINX (on EC2 instance)
- Server container (Docker container in EKS k8s cloud)
- Inside the server container: gunicorn + Flask

I checked the request/error logs for NGINX & gunicorn and added custom request logs in Flask in the `before_request` and `after_request` hooks. Those are the results for a request that get's lost:

- First nothing appears in any of the log files for 60 seconds.
- Then the NGINX error log reads:

```
2023/06/12 11:58:54 [error] 185547#185547: *13387 upstream timed out 
(110: Unknown error) while connecting to upstream, client: XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX,
 server: *.example.com, request: "GET /api/some-route HTTP/1.1", upstream: 
"http://XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX:5000/api/some-route", host: "subdomain.example.com", 
referrer: "https://subdomain.example.com/some/frontend/route"
```

- Afterwards all logs read like intended. The NGINX, gunicorn and flask access logs show the request that is retried automatically (?) after the timeout.

As neither of the upstream error or access logs show anything, my guess is, that NGINX is the root of the issue. What is happening here?

Here is my site config:

```
server {
        root /var/www/html;

        index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;
        server_name *.example.com;


        location / {
                proxy_pass https://frontend.address;
        }

        location /api {
                proxy_pass http://some-aws-eks-adress.amazonaws.com:5000;
        }
}
```

After restarting NGINX, the issue is gone for same days - then comes again.

Answer (score 0):

Faced similar issue. Check for conntrack limits and current values using below commands.

Check how many active connections are being tracked.

```
cat /proc/sys/net/netfilter/nf_conntrack_count
```

Check the current max value of nf_conntrack

```
cat /proc/sys/net/netfilter/nf_conntrack_max
```

Change the value temporarily to something higher (please note, that increasing this number will likely increase the system resource usage and load as it will be handling more connections at a time)

```
echo 50000 > /proc/sys/net/netfilter/nf_conntrack_max
```

To make this change permanent, please add the following line to the end /etc/sysctl.conf

```
net.netfilter.nf_conntrack_max = 500000
```

To help lessen the issues with a large number of connections, you may want to consider reducing the amount of time the server waits until it closes/timeouts the connections.

To do this, add the following lines to the end /etc/sysctl.conf

```
net.netfilter.nf_conntrack_tcp_timeout_close_wait = 60
net.netfilter.nf_conntrack_tcp_timeout_fin_wait = 60
net.netfilter.nf_conntrack_tcp_timeout_time_wait = 60
```

Comment: Just saw your comment, a little late.. `nf_conntrack_count` is 0 while I'm experiencing the issue, so I guess my issue has a different cause..